# How to parse xml file to js and then display it in react native

Tags: xml, react-native

I have tried to parse xml file using react-native-xml2js package but unable to resolve an issue.

Comment: Can you share the issue?

Comment: May you please suggest me how can I use a loop and read all tags(also their values) in javascript?

Comment: `const C = <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
      <Library>
         <Books count='1'>
             <Book id='1'>
                 <Name>Me Before You</Name>
                 <Author>Jojo Moyes</Author>
             </Book>
         </Books>
         <Music count=1>
             <CD id='2'>
                 <Name>Houses of the Holy</Name>
                 <Artist>Led Zeppelin</Artist>
             </CD>
         </Music>
      </Library>`
This is my xml content in C variable

Comment: How i parse all xml in loop, how to loop on Books and have their child and their values?